# T-SQL UNION between two queries with different order by, all orded by

Tags: sql-server, union

As the title I have this problem:

I have these two queries

```
SELECT state, TIMESTAMP
FROM myTable
WHERE state != 9
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC

SELECT TOP (3) state, TIMESTAMP
FROM myTable
WHERE state = 9
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

is it possible to `ORDER BY` again (`ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC`) the `UNION` of these queries?

Thank you

EDIT: to be more specific

I have a table with `[state]` and `[timestamp]` fields. `[State]` value can be 3, 8 or 9.
What I need is to select:
`[state] = 9`   last 3 records
`[state] != 9`  all

all `ORDER BY [timestamp] ASC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT [state], [TIMESTAMP]
FROM
(
    SELECT [state], [TIMESTAMP]
    FROM   myTable
    WHERE  [state] != 9   

    UNION 

    SELECT TOP(3) [state], [TIMESTAMP]
    FROM          myTable
    WHERE         [state] = 9
    ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] DESC
) u
ORDER BY [TIMESTAMP] ASC
```

The order by of the first query is redundant in the union, but the second query needs it for the `top(3)`, otherwise you get 3 arbitrary rows.

Comment: @sagi read the text under the code - the order by in the second query is necessary since it has top specified.

Comment: If the intention is that all of the rows with `state` not equal to 9 appear before the "top 3" rows, that should also be made explicit in the outer `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever while your comment is true, I didn't see that requirement in the question.

Comment: Thanks for answers!

Zohar Peled, I tried your samples but it seems it does not work...

Sagi, realized that the order by on each query is meaningless I have my problem again. Maybe I used the wrong way to resolve my problem...

I need to select last three fields with [state] equals to 9 and the other fields with [state] different from 9, all order by [timestamp] asc.

Is there any different way? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? if you can edit your question to include the ddl of the table, some sample data (prefrebly as dml statements) and desired output, I'm sure we can make it work as desired.

Comment: I tried your code but I got this error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'."  I'm going to edit my question to be more specific.

Comment: @ZoharPeled RESOLVED! I missed the "u" copying your sample. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT state, TIMESTAMP
    FROM myTable
    WHERE state != 9
    UNION
    SELECT TOP (3) state, TIMESTAMP
    FROM myTable
    WHERE state = 9
    ORDER BY (CASE WHEN state = 9 THEN TIMESTAMP END ) DESC
        ,(CASE WHEN state != 9 THEN TIMESTAMP END ) ASC
)   D
```

Comment: Whoa, that's genial! I didn't know the use of CASE construct within the ORDER BY clause was possible, and I think it is the only solution when the the sorting field is the same across the selection!I enjoyed it!